# Redirection of Form after submitted

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Ruby on **rails 5.1**, How can I redirect the User to the Edit Page after submitting the form successfully after login_in in his page after a Long Time

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand what you want to do. What kind of Edit Page? Edit model named 'Page'? What mean Long Time?

Comment: I am not sure what page the user would like to edit.
btw  in the create method I would put `if your_instance_variable.save  render :edit end`

Comment: @PiotrGalas ,if a user a signed_up in to the forum through filling the form. Now If a user wanted to change the detail again .How can I redirect him to edit the form again rather creating a new form

Comment: @mark, I had a same idea of implementing in that way

Comment: and does it work? @SriramS

Comment: I think @mark solution could work. I recommend you to generate sample scaffold (google how to do it). Then you can read controller code (edit  and create actions). There are only few easy to understand lines. You will see where and how to use redirect.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I would do this way, let me know if it works

```
  def create
    @your_instance_variable = YourInstanceVariable.new(your_params)
      if @your_instance_variable.save
        render :edit
      else
       #do something else...
      end
  end
```